# Explanation of a program related to python lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
list_1 = ["A", "B", "C"]
list_2 = list_1
list_3 = list_2
 
del list_1[0]
del list_2
 
print(list_3)
```

Output is `['B', 'C']`

Why the output is like that? Where is 'A'?
I need a explanation for this program.

Answer (score 1):

There are two distinct meanings of `del`.

```
del list1[0]
```

means remove the zero'th element from `list1`.

```
del list2
```

means remove the `list2` **variable** from the scope in which it was declared.  If you were to add a `print(list2)` statement, you would see the effect that this has.

So ... what happens is as follows.

1. Before the first `del`, we have `list1`, `list2` and `list3` all pointing to the same `list` object containing `['A', 'B', 'C']`.
2. After the first `del`, we have `list1`, `list2` and `list3` all pointing to the same `list` object as before, but it now contains `['B', 'C']`; i.e. the first element has been removed.
3. After the second `del`, we no longer have a `list2` variable.  And `list1` and `list3` *still* point to `['B', 'C']`.

---

In short:

> Where is 'A'?

It has been removed from the (shared) `list` object by the first `del` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear what else you expect list_3 to have. There is a difference between doing...

```
list_2 = list_1
```

...and...

```
list_2 = list_1.copy()
```